# Wasserstein Distance from Riemannian Metric?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Given the metric space of the probability distributions over $A=\{1,2,...,n\}$, where the metric is the the 1st or 2nd Wasserstein distance (with respect to the metric $d(i,j)=|i-j|,\ \ i,j\in A$), is it possible to equip the space with a Riemannian inner product (metric) such that the space is a complete Riemannian manifold, and the length of the shortest geodesic between any two points (probability distributions) equals the Wasserstein distance between them?

If the answer is positive:

- Is there an explicit representation of the Riemannian metric?
- Do geodesics in this space have some interpretation as the optimal mass transport paths?

Comment: This may help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277567/manifold-of-probability-measures-connections-between-two-types-of-metrics

Comment: Of course it can't literally be a Riemannian manifold because by the usual definitions those are finite dimensional.  You might ask whether it's a Hilbert manifold, and it seems from the link above that it isn't.

Comment: @NateEldredge your're right, I edited the question to refer to finite dimensions